# SQL - The percentage of responses out of the total responses, grouped per country

Tags: sql, sql-server

So *country* has *questions* which has *answers*. I want the percentage of how many selected an answer from a specific question out of all the answers in that question, grouped by country.

Note there are multiple instances of the same question per country, each with different number of individual answers. There is also a field containing the total_nr_responses per answer/entry.

Sample Data

```
question_id   country    answer_key   total_nr_responses
A1            Austria    A1_B1        3
A1            Austria    A1_B1        0
A1            Austria    A1_B2        4
A1            Belgium    A1_B1        4
A1            Belgium    A1_B1        10
A2            Austria    A2_B1        2
...
```

Expected Result for question A1, answer A1_B1 as percentage of the total_nr_responses for a specific answer out of the total responses, per country (100x3/7):

```
 Country   Result
 Austria   percentage
 Belgium   percentage
```

I tried something like this but I am not sure how to get the percentage per country/ how to group in the sub query per country so that the whole query works:

```
Select Country, count(total_nr_responses)* 100 / (Select count(total_nr_responses) From my_table WHERE question_key = 'A1') as percentage
From my_table
WHERE question_id = 'A1' AND answer_key = 'A1_B1'
GROUP BY Country
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: For SQL Server, you'll be using the OVER(PARTITION BY) to reset your numbers within country groups.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks, updated question

Comment: req. output is not clear.Under Result column write figure.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this is what you're looking for?

```
SELECT
  mt.country,
  SUM(mt.total_nr_responses) * 100 / p.total_sum_responses
FROM
  my_table AS mt,
  ( SELECT country, SUM(total_nr_responses) AS total_sum_responses FROM my_table WHERE question_id = 'A1' GROUP BY country ) AS p
WHERE
  question_id = 'A1' AND
  answer_key = 'A1_B1' AND
  p.country = mt.country
GROUP BY
  mt.country,
  p.total_sum_responses
```

I wasn't able to make it work with OVER(PARTITION BY) because of the percent calculation. It'd be great to see what Cade Roux had in mind fully spelled out in code.

Execution plans between the nested SELECT and the CROSS APPLY are pretty similar and all three (window function, cross-apply and nested-select) yield similar results. If dealing with large amounts of data, make sure you have a composite index on the country, and question_id. Great to see such diverse solutions to the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

How about using `CROSS APPLY` to get the total?

**Query**

```
SELECT mt.question_id, mt.country, mt.answer_key, (SUM(mt.total_nr_responses) * 100 / ca.total_nr_responses) AS result
FROM my_table mt
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(total_nr_responses) AS total_nr_responses
             FROM my_table
             WHERE question_id = mt.question_id AND country = mt.country) ca
WHERE mt.question_id = 'A1' AND mt.answer_key = 'A1_B1'
GROUP BY mt.question_id, mt.country, mt.answer_key, ca.total_nr_responses
```

**Output**

```
+-------------+---------+------------+--------+
| question_id | country | answer_key | result |
+-------------+---------+------------+--------+
|     A1      | Austria |    A1_B1   |   42   |
|     A1      | Belgium |    A1_B1   |  100   |
+-------------+---------+------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM` function with a window specification.

```
select distinct country,
question_id,
answer_key,
100.0*sum(total_nr_responses) over(partition by country,question_id,answer_key)/
sum(total_nr_responses) over(partition by country,question_id) as pct
from my_table
```

Add a `where` clause to restrict the result to specific questions/answers/countries, if needed.

Comment: Thanks for that example. I don't like the repeats of the rows (e.g. if more than one row existed with the same country, question_id and answer_key but different total_nr_responses) ... but it's a good example of window functions.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would do this with a simple window function along with aggregation:

```
Select Country,
       count(total_nr_responses) * 100 / sum(count(total_nr_responses)) over () as percentage
From my_table
where question_id = 'A1' AND answer_key = 'A1_B1'
group by Country;
```

Note:  SQL Server does integer division.  I would change the `100` to `100.0` and format the result after the division.  Otherwise, the values won't come close to adding up to 100.